# BIOS/UEFI Multiboot Suggestions

Tags: usb, multi-boot, uefi, grub2

I do a lot of tech work, including building PC's and some file system repairs; re-installs.

I'm looking to create a hybrid BIOS/UEFI thumb drive that has a vast collection of linux distro mini images and some windows images, along with tools such as HirenPE, PartedMagic, Anti-virus and UBCD.

After spending a few days scouring Google, and trying multiple tools, I've resigned to doing most of the work from scratch, but need suggestions on a good bootloader that can support displaying the same menu in both BIOS and UEFI mode; and boot in each mode properly based on the UEFI mode the end-user (myself mostly) chooses.

I can understand and code most INI/CFG files, but need some suggestions on where I should start when doing so from the bottom, up.

I've tried a few programs so far, such as YUMI, xBoot, AIOBoot, SARDU and a few others, but most of these programs are limited in scope, allowing only for certain images to be mounted or added. SARDU wants you to buy pro just to add some of the ISO's (which would be cool if it worked the way I needed it to).

Answer (score 0):

Mixing Legacy and UEFI booting is very difficult because UEFI booting uses a flat file structure (you cant have multiple versions of files of the same name in the same folder!).
XBOOT is Legacy only. SARDU, WinSetupfromUSB , AIOBoot and Easy2Boot do support both UEFI and Legacy but in various different ways.

I am the developer of Easy2Boot (E2B). It is quite easy to use for Legacy booting (especially for booting Linux Legacy ISOs) and it is very configurable. For UEFI, you have to switch-in a .imgPTN partition image (similar to AIOBoot which copied my approach). The website has YT videos as well as free email or online Chat help. Due to various BIOS bugs, it is usually best to have one E2B USB drive for Legacy and the other for UEFI. E2B eBooks are also available with Exercises ;-).

The other approach is to use grub2 as the UEFI+Legacy boot loader. The problem with this is that you will probably have to hand-craft many Linux ISO menus and it has problems UEFI-multibooting Windows Install payloads, etc.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback SSi, I actually discoverd E2B while I was away from this question. It is very intuitive and customizable. I'm trying to create a usb stick that will allow me to cover all tech needs rather than carry around my binder of discs.

One thing I'm thinking of is building a PE that downloads a windows install wim/esd instead of having it on the drive if I can help it. Similar to windows, I plan on using linux mini iso's that serve the core of the os through the distro mirrors, again to conserve space. I'll read through the sites knowledgebase.